# Forward redis pubsub message to specific socket.io client in express

Tags: node.js, express, redis, socket.io

In my express server, I am using socket.io and Redis pubsub.
The server subscribes a Redis message channel, and forwards Redis message to a specific websocket client when someone publishes new message via Redis.

From what i read from socket.io and Redis documentation, I can send message to a specific client by using the varible `socket` and call `socket.broadcast.to(mySocketID).emit`.

But in the following code, what should I do if I wanna emit message to `mySocketID` inside the redis subscriber, which is out of the scope of `io.on('connection')`?

```js
var redis = require('redis');
var server = require('http').createServer(app);
var io = require("socket.io")(server);

io.on('connection', function (socket) {

   socket.on('whatever_event', function() {
       socket.broadcast.to(mySocketID).emit('TEST', 'hello ' + mySocketID);
   }
}

var subscriber = redis.createClient();

subscriber.on('message', function (channel, redisMessage) {

// I want to send redisMessage to the websocket client
// Can I access to "socket" in io.on('connection' ...) ? 

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did something similar with WebSockets a while back (If I understand what you're trying to do). Effectively, I had to create a in-process event proxy layer between the Redis Pub/Sub (plain ol' EventEmitter) and the websocket. Without this layer you're going to have a lot of unneeded connection overhead, by using it you can limit the number of open connections to Redis.

So, the `subscriber.on` section sends a EventEmitter event (`yourEventsObject.emit(/*...*/)`). Then inside your socket.io connection callback you respond to these events with listeners (`yourEventsObject.on(/*...*/)`). When your socket.io connection closes, you need to make sure and clean up these EventEmitter listeners so you don't get errors with closed sockets.

Here is the full file on [full source on](https://github.com/stockholmux/data-stream-pub-sub/blob/master/manager.node.js) and the [article describing the problem/solution with websockets](https://medium.com/@stockholmux/grab-your-hardhat-b639d4f7fe07).